# TextView expands layout but webview does not

Tags: android-layout

I've got a layout with a textview with some buttons at the bottom. The textview is set to expand to fill the space. This is fine. However, when I change the textview to a webview, the webview does not expand to fill the space. What's wrong?

This is working fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
    <!-- height set to fill because background is black and we want 
        the light background -->
    <TextView
        style="@style/subtopicView"
        android:id="@+id/subtopic_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         />
    </ScrollView>

    <include layout="@layout/include_html_view_footer" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is not, but the only change is the textview to a webview and all other values remain the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
    <!-- height set to fill because background is black and we want 
        the light background -->
         <WebView
             style="@style/subtopicView"
        android:id="@+id/subtopic_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </ScrollView>

    <include layout="@layout/include_html_view_footer" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the include is simply this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/tintedColour"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacer"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacer" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/PrevPage"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/previous" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/NextPage"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/next" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Copy"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/copyclipboard" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to nest scrollable elements like you have done by including a WebView inside a ScrollView. Touch events will be unpredictable, and it would probably be a better idea to drop the ScrollView altogether.

That said, the height of your WebView is set to `fill_parent`. However, the ScrollView is simultaneously trying to minimize the size of its children. [As Romain Guy writes in a blog post on this topic](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/):

> In attempt to achieve this effect, I have seen several Android developers try to set the height of the view inside the scroll view to fill_parent. Doing so does not work and leads to the following result:
>
> [image: FillScrollView example by Romain Guy]
>
> To understand this result, you must remember that android:layout_height=”fill_parent” means “set the height to the height of the parent.” This is obviously not what you want when using a ScrollView. After all, the ScrollView would become useless if its content was always as tall as itself.

By setting `android:fillViewport="true"`, the scroll view’s child expands to the height of the ScrollView. (When the child is taller than the ScrollView, the attribute has no effect.)

Comment: thanks, sorry I forgot to +1 this. I guess I assumed because I need to use scrollbar layout around the textview I had to do the same with the webview. Plus using fillviewport means I could remove the warning about using fill_parent and use wrap_content :)